# How can I enable uniqueness validation when the submit string matched with existing lower case string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

When the user A submits `california`, it saves this as new record.
Then if the user B submits `California`, it saves this as new record, too.

I don't want that:( I want it recognize as the same string even when if it's in upper case or lower case.

Is it possible?

My current code is just like this.

**models/community.rb**

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :message => "is already existing. Please type something else!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uniqueness validator has a `case_sensitive` option which you can set to `false`.  More of it in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of).